# SQL server refusing to cache plan for a fixed length parameterized IN clause

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

Using .NET 4.0, I have defined the following sqlcommand.  When I execute the sqlcommand multiple times consecutively without making any changes, SQL Server refuses to cache the query plan.

```
string[] colors = new string[] { "red", "blue", "yellow", "green" };
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM ColoredProducts WHERE Color IN ({0})";

string[] paramNames = tags.Select(
    (s, i) => "@color" + i.ToString()
).ToArray();

string inClause = string.Join(",", paramNames);
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format(cmdText, inClause))) {
    for(int i = 0; i < paramNames.Length; i++) {
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], tags[i]);
    }
    //Execute query here
}
```

I know it's refusing the cache the plan because the following query was running at a fraction of the time after consecutive runs:

```
string[] colors = new string[] { "red", "blue", "yellow", "green" };
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM ColoredProducts WHERE Color IN ({0})";

string inClause = string.Join(",", colors);
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format(cmdText, inClause))) {
       //Execute query here
}
```

In my actual test case the param list is fixed at a size of exactly 2000.  The scenario I am attempting to optimize is selecting a specific set of 2000 records from a very large table.  I would like for the query to be as fast as possible so I really want it to cached.

Sleepy post Edit:
The question is, why wouldn't this plan get cached?  And yes, I have confirmed that the query is not in the cache using sys.dm_exec_cached_plans and sys.dm_exec_sql_test.

Comment: If your primary goal is speed, why not use a stored procedure with TVPs instead of building this massive IN string? Also did you actually confirm the presence/absence of the plan in cache, or are you just assuming that because the larger version of the query runs slower?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea using a table-valued parameter. Please let us know if this approach performs better than your huge string. There are other ideas too, but this is the closest to treating your set of colors as an array.

In SQL Server:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Colors AS TABLE
(
  Color VARCHAR(32) -- be precise here! Match ColoredProducts.Color
     PRIMARY KEY
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MatchColors
  @colors AS dbo.Colors READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT cp.* -- use actual column names please!
  FROM dbo.ColoredProducts AS cp -- always use schema prefix
  INNER JOIN @colors AS c
  ON cp.Color = c.Color; 
END
GO
```

Now in C#:

```
DataTable tvp = new DataTable();
tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Color"));

tvp.Rows.Add("red"); 
tvp.Rows.Add("blue"); 
tvp.Rows.Add("yellow"); 
tvp.Rows.Add("green"); 
// ...

using (connectionObject)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.MatchColors", connectionObject);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter tvparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colors", tvp);
    tvparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    // execute query here
}
```

I can almost guarantee this will perform better than an `IN` list with a large number of parameters, regardless of the length of the actual string in your C# code.

Comment: @Bogdan I had assumed that the list constructed in C# would be unique. I added a PK to the table variable to be sure, but the calling code will still have to ensure that the DataTable doesn't contain any duplicates.